# How do I map over two arrays at the same time in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, array-map

How do I map over two different arrays in react native? In my case I'm fetching a response from server and mapping over it. Also there is another array named `images` which I want to list along with the fetched response from server.But the second mapping is looping within the first one. How do I separate it from the first?Following is my code.

**sample code**

```
<ScrollView>
  {this.state.workers.map(a =>
    <CardSection>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.popupDialog.show()}>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 10, marginLeft:120}}>
          {images.map(b =>
            <Image
              style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
              source={{ uri: b.image }}
             />
           )}
           <Text style={{marginLeft:20, fontSize:20}}>{a.work_type}</Text>
         </View>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </CardSection>
   )}
```

`workers` array is the json response I'm fetching from server.`images` array is as folows

```
export const images = [
  {
    image:'http://localhost:3000/Images/carpenter.png',
    text:'hello'
  },
  {
    image:'http://localhost:3000/Images/electrician.png',
    text:'hii'
  },
]
```

Also this how `workers` array looks like

**updated**

```
 [
        {
            "sl.no": 1,
            "worker_id": "wr_1",
            "work_type": "carpenter",
            "phone_num": "3456789243"
        },
        {
            "sl.no": 2,
            "worker_id": "wr_2",
            "work_type": "electrician",
            "phone_num": "345221344"
        },
        {
            "sl.no": 3,
            "worker_id": "wr_3",
            "work_type": "plumber",
            "phone_num": "8976545677"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What is the issue with the code you pasted above?

Comment: Are you trying to render Image component for every worker or just once? A bit confused

Comment: `this.state.workers.map((a, index) => { let b = images[index]; return ... })`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move it above the first map and save the result:

```
render() {
  const imagesToRender = images.map(b => {
    return (
      <Image
        style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
        source={{ uri: b.image }}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {this.state.workers.map(a =>
        <CardSection>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.popupDialog.show()}>
            <View style={{ marginTop: 10, marginLeft:120}}>
              {imagesToRender}
              <Text style={{marginLeft:20, fontSize:20}}>{a.work_type}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </CardSection>
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Also, don't forget to add [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) props to each `Image` and each `CardSection`.

Comment: This OP original code is alright. This answer just refactored it by moving the nested mapping to a separate constant.

Comment: @FirmanWijaya that's my understand of what OP is asking: how to avoid doing the inner `.map` on every iteration of the outer `.map`

Comment: @Firman Wijaya I've tried your code but images are not displaying please check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAnI7.png

Comment: @Firman Wijaya the problem was accessing to localhost image i changed it with my ip. But the images are repeating within a single card check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozxCH.png

Comment: @anu Then you can use index to access the `images` array, assuming the server response (`workers`) matches the `images` array. Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use flatlist with better performance

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Image, Text } from "react-native";

const workers = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Nima', images: [{ image: 'https://www.lens-rumors.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Nikon-AF-S-DX-Nikkor-18-140mm-f3.5-5.6G-ED-VR-sample-images1.jpg', text: 'hello' },{ image: 'https://www.lens-rumors.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Nikon-AF-S-DX-Nikkor-18-140mm-f3.5-5.6G-ED-VR-sample-images1.jpg', text: 'hello' },{ image: 'https://www.lens-rumors.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Nikon-AF-S-DX-Nikkor-18-140mm-f3.5-5.6G-ED-VR-sample-images1.jpg', text: 'hello' },{ image: 'https://www.lens-rumors.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Nikon-AF-S-DX-Nikkor-18-140mm-f3.5-5.6G-ED-VR-sample-images1.jpg', text: 'hello' }] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Mike', images: [{ image: 'https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image', text: 'goodby' },{ image: 'https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image', text: 'goodby' },{ image: 'https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image', text: 'goodby' },{ image: 'https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image', text: 'goodby' },] },
]

class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            workers: workers
        };
    }

    _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        console.log(item);
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={{ marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 120 }}>
                        {item.images.map((b, index) => {
                            console.log(b.image);
                            return (
                                <View key={index}>
                                    <Image
                                        style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
                                        source={{ uri: b.image }}
                                    />
                                    <Text
                                        style={{ marginLeft: 20, fontSize: 20, color: "black" }}
                                    >
                                        {b.text}
                                    </Text>
                                </View>
                            );
                        })}
                        <Text style={{ marginLeft: 20, fontSize: 20, color: "black" }}>
                            {item.name}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    };

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id.toString();

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.workers}
                extraData={this.state}
                keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the images don't load, it's probably because you pass the wrong properties to the `<Image />` component. Look up the docs for `<Image />` component or replace it with `<img />` instead and pass the url string of the image to the `src` attribute.

```
getImageUri(worker) {
  // Decide which image to return for a certain type of worker
  // For more workers and images, change the following logic
  if(worker.work_type == 'carpenter') {
    return images[0].image;
  } else if(worker.work_type == 'electrician') {
    return images[1].image;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

render() {
...
<ScrollView>
  {this.state.workers.map((a, index) =>
    <CardSection>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.popupDialog.show()}>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 10, marginLeft:120}}>
            <Image
              style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
              source={{ uri: this.getImageUri(a)}}
             />
           <Text style={{marginLeft:20, fontSize:20}}>{a.work_type}</Text>
         </View>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </CardSection>
   )}
</ScrollView>
...
}
```

Comment: Here where do I write code for mapping the images array?Also I'm getting error on this code.

Comment: @anu you don't map the `images` array but access them using array index. If the `workers` array matches the `images` array, you can simply access `images` array by index.

Comment: @FirmanWijaya what if he has more than one image in his array ?

Comment: @FirmanWijaya I'm getting cannot read property image of undefined.

Comment: @anu: that means you have more elements in `workers` array than in `images` array. Simply check which image to use using ternary operator then. Answer updated

Comment: @FirmanWijaya so for each item in array do I need to check?What do I do if I've more items in `images` array?Also in `workers` array?Do I need to check each `work_type` with the image item ?

Comment: @anu you can create a separate function to determine what image to return for a certain type of worker, and call that function as the value of uri property. Answer updated

Comment: There also I've to check the condition using ternary operator ryt?How do I give else if condition?

Comment: @anu simply change the ternary op to else if. Answer updated